# Symfony upload file and save filename with id, work, when saving into database not work

Tags: php, symfony

```
/**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            $this->path = $this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
        // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
        // which the UploadedFile move() method does
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->id.'.'.$this->file->guessExtension());

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
    }
```

hi in this cose i upload the file
 when i saving the filename id into directory all work, but into database saving jpg only...without id

Comment: 10 questions and no accepted answers... Please go back to your previous questions, and mark the answer that solved your issue as accepted by clicking the 'tick' icon underneath the answer's votes.

Comment: aaaa ok i not know this method ok wait

Comment: I don't understand the question: what does not work? Do you see anything in the database? If yes, what?

Comment: in database
id  name         path
1  utkukur  jpg

Answer (score 2):

In the pre persist lifecycle call back your entity has not yet been assigned an ID therefore `$this->id.'.'.$this->file->guessExtension()` when calling this, `$this->id` will be `null`

You have followed the example in the cookbook correctly. It just fails to mention that the only thing stored in the database under path will be the extension. This doesn't matter as the filename will always be the id concatenated with the extension. i.e. `$filename = $this->id . $this->path`

You will therefore have to think of a different naming strategy if you want the string stored under the path to exactly represent the filename.

Answer (score 0):

In your preUpload method, you just affect the extension file to the path property. So, it's normal in your database you just have the jpg extension.

EDIT: In your preUpload method, the ID is not yet affected by the ORM, so you can't use it to generate the file name. IMO, you should use uniquid to generate a unique file name. Something like `$this->path = uniquid().'.'.$this->file->guessExtension()`

Comment: if i add 
$this->path = $this->id.'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
always save only jpg, without id

Answer (score 0):

Okay i had the same problem once(only with .txt).

I think it might be a problem if you have special charakters in your filename.

i solved it this way:

```
            $filepath = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filepath = str_replace(array('/',  ' ', '-', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü', 'ß'), array('_', '_', '', 'ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'Ae', 'Oe', 'Ue', 'ss'), $filepath);
        $this->path = $filepath;
```

hope this is the answer for your problem, if it isn't solved yet anyways :D